# can't ignore the enter key

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this is my code

when i press enter to insert a value for n, it right away move to the next loop
without to press a second time
i have try to clean the buffer with cin.clear(), cin.syns(),... but it not work

anyone know why and how to fix it

thanks

```
int main() {
    bool isNotExit=true;
    do {
        isNotExit=menu();
    } while( isNotExit );
    return 0;
}

bool menu() {
    int n;
    do {
        cout<<"n = "<<endl;
        cin>>n;cin.ignore(1);
    } while( n!=1&&n!=2&&n!=3 );
    switch( n ) {
    case 1:
    {
        cout<<"Press enter to continue"<<endl;
        bool enter=false;
        do {
            if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)&0x8000 ) enter=true;
        } while( enter==false );
        return true;
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {

        return true;
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    {
        return false;
    }
    break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it happens is system specific. I can not reproduce the issue on my computer, but I guess it is all about this line:

```
if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)&0x8000 ) enter=true;
```

Before the system realized that you have released 'Enter' for entering the `n` it already checks it in the line specified above. Try this:

```
case 1:
{
    sleep(1); // Proof of concept
    cout<<"Press enter to continue"<<endl;
    bool enter=false;
    do {
        if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)&0x8000 ) enter=true;
    } while( enter==false );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the asker is wrong, just leave him alone solving his problems, he does not appreciate and deserve help

Comment: thanks for the answer but i didn't downvote you, i even don't log in since yesterday, that was something wrong

Comment: and because i was less than 15 repulation, i even can't downvote you